# is the front/back (.Fr .Bk) naming convention useful for mirror weight painting or poses? why does it exist?

Tags: animation, rigging

I just discovered this exist and I'm curious to know if it actually helps in something, like mirror weight painting or poses on "Y" axis.
[image]

Comment: For rigging quadrupeds?